# DropDown menu with hover on parent text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following is basic working DropDown menu, child’s appear on parent hover.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#nav li').hover(
      function () {
      //show its submenu
        $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);
      }, 
      function () {
      //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(100); 
      }
    );
  });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
  #nav li {background-color:#CCC; }
</style>

<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#" class="selected">Parent A</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item a1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="selected">Item a2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item a3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Parent B</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item b1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item b2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item b3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item b4</a></li>
    </ul> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Currently child’s appears when hover is anywhere on the area of the parent box (i.e. also outside the text, on the invisible area of the parent div).

I want the child’s to appear only on hover of the parent link (on the ‘href’ text only).

I couldn’t find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `a` element as target for `hover` instead of the entire `li`, as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#nav ul').hide();

    $('#nav li > a').hover(
      function () {
      //show its submenu
        $('ul', this.parentNode).stop().slideDown(100);
      }
    );
   $('#nav li').hover(null, 
      function (e) {
      //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this.parentNode).stop().slideUp(100); 
      }
   );
  });
</script>
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7GGab/) .

Comment: @ Nelson. Thanks very much, this is really a nice solution. I’m trying now to add a third level but with your JavaScript code I cannot get it done. Please see the following link, I didn’t get any reply, please could you help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810487/dropdown-multilevel-menu-with-hover

Comment: Yes, I've posted an answer to that question with new code to handle a third level, you now have enough reputation to give upvotes, so if you think my answer is correct you can upvote it too (up arrow) if you are happy with it :-).